# PHP Image upload not working yet everything seems correct?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Im trying to build a simple, singular image upload that accepts jpg, jpeg, gif and png formats.

I've tried the following only I have no luck and constantly receive `invalid file`

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

My HTML Form is...

```
<form method="post" action="process-signup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="profile_image"  />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: please print_r($_FILE);

Comment: Mostly for CSS and jQuery, of which is is client side @Ahmed - not sure if you knew that, surprise.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="file" name="file"  />
```

Comment: I still receive invalid file @messifan

Comment: please print_r($_FILE);

Answer (score 1):

change this line to `<input type="file" name="profile_image"  />`

```
<input type="file" name="file"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES is a PHP global var that store all data while uploading data to server. Its has all these data in array format e,g. $_FILES[FORM_ELEMENT_NAME]['name'], $_FILES[FORM_ELEMENT_NAME]['type'] etc

FORM_ELEMENT_NAME - is the name of the input element used in the form

`<input type="file" name="FORM_ELEMENT_NAME">`

In your code you have used it wrong. In HTML you have put

`<input type="file" name="profile_image"  />` i.e. profile_image

and in PHP you have used $_FILES["**file**"]["name"] i.e. file

change the form element name either in HTML or in PHP script